# What's a real life example of linearization of a system around a fixed point

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, nonlinear-control

I'm tasked on finding a example of a real non-linear control system. a real paper or publication on a website like the IEEE thats describes the model of the system so I can then linearizy it around a fixed point an simulate it.
I'm having trouble using the correct keywords or the right type of system to find a good example so I can do what I'm tasked so I'm asking for advice here on how to google it on any of those research and publication sites or if you know any good example.

Comment: Check on Google Scholar with the request "linearization control". You will find plenty.